# Why won't Mathematica Conjugate this expression>

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation, complex

I've been trying to replicate the derivation of Bloch's equations in Mathematica and for the final substitution, it won't correctly conjugate the expression even though I specify that all of the symbols are real (except the $I$'s of course)

```
abar = (-I γ + δ1) ab[t] - A bb[t] - 2 I Derivative[1][ab][t]
bbar = -A ab[t] - I ((γ - I δ1) bb[t] + 2 Derivative[1][bb][t])

{δ1, γ, δ2, A, J, ab[t], bb[t], cb[t], db[t], ab'[t], bb'[t], cb'[t], db'[t]} ∈ Reals

FullSimplify[abar*Conjugate[abar] - bbar*Conjugate[bbar]]
```

(there are more symbols defined as real because this is part of an expanded notebook) and this gives

```
(Conjugate[(-I γ + δ1) ab[t] - A bb[t]] + 
    2 I Conjugate[
      Derivative[1][ab][t]]) ((-I γ + δ1) ab[t] - 
    A bb[t] - 
    2 I Derivative[1][ab][t]) + (-Conjugate[
      A ab[t] + (I γ + δ1) bb[t]] + 
    2 I Conjugate[Derivative[1][bb][t]]) (A ab[
      t] + (I γ + δ1) bb[t] + 2 I Derivative[1][bb][t])
```

as output, and just using

```
Conjugate[abar]
```

gives

```
Conjugate[(-I γ + δ1) ab[t] - A bb[t]] + 2 I Conjugate[Derivative[1][ab][t]]
```

Many thanks

Comment: `{list of symbols}\[Element] Reals` does absolutely nothing. *Mathematica* is not a programming language in the sense you're tying to use it here. Check out `tutorial/SimplifyingWithAssumptions`. But first, maybe `ComplexExpand` is what you really want.

Comment: Many thanks, this solved the problem.